# lambda expression meaning

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

I have created an htmlhelper which has signature like this:

```
 public static MvcHtmlString PageLinks(this HtmlHelper html,
     PagingInfo pagingInfo,Func<int, string> pageUrl)
```

and I see that It is passed like this:

```
@Html.PageLinks(Model.PagingInfo, x => Url.Action("List", new {page = x}))
```

but I dont know what is it meaning ?

```
x => Url.Action("List", new {page = x})
```

Please suggest meaning of this lambda expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's a lambda expression which takes a single parameter called `x` and is implicitly typed to be a `int`, and which calls `Url.Action` with one argument of the string `"List"` another argument of an anonymous type which has a single property `page` with the value of the parameter `x`.

The value returned from `Url.Action` is used as the return value for the lambda expression.

That's how the lambda expression itself is broken down, in terms of language constructs. If you're asking what it means in terms of *behaviour*, that's a different matter - you'd need to look at your own `PageLinks` method, as well as the documentation for `Url.Action`.

Comment: Just to add, I think that you'll benefit from reading about delegates, as Func<int, string> is a delegate that accepts int as input and returns string. When it comes to generating your page links, you delegate creation of your links to Url.Action

Comment: @jon what will be the value of x ?

Answer (score 1):

```
x => Url.Action("List", new {page = x})
```

This is a (lambda) function that given an `x` (and we know that `x` must be integer because the signature is `Func<int, string>`) returns an url (the string). (technically it is a lambda expression, but the difference is lost in this particular case)

You use it like this: `string url = pageUrl(pageNumber);`

`Url.Action` gives the url of the action `List` that has a single parameter (of type `int` and name `page` probably) that will be filled with the value of `x`. This parameter will probably be the page of the list that must be returned.

```
@Html.PageLinks(Model.PagingInfo, x => Url.Action("List", new {page = x}))
```

This will "return" an html string with a link to the url we calculated before. (probably an `<a href='url'></a>` or something similar) ah... it's your function :-)

(I think you are doing something like this: [ASP.NET MVC Paging, Preserving Current Query Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430595/asp-net-mvc-paging-preserving-current-query-parameters) with the `PagingInfo` class containing the current and total pages, right?)

Comment: exactly :) but I am not sure the process. what is called first. controller , view or helper ? Please suggest. thanks.

Comment: @DotnetSparrow (I hope I'm not doing errors... Much time since last programmed MVC) Let's say that you have page MyPage (1) (where (1) is the parameter passed to the page). MyPage (1) will need a link to MyPage (2) (with the next 20 rows of the table for example). The order is: controller of MyPage (1) (MyController for example) calls view of MyPage (1). During rendering of MyPage (1) (composing of html) the renderer at the row where the helper is called and calls it. The helper creates a link to MyPage (2). The remaining part of the page is "prepared" (the html is composed)